# c++ how to sum all rows from one specific column from a csv delimited

Tags: c++

I have a question in C++
For example, i have a csv file delimited by `;` with this data

```
name;age;country
maria;19;portugal
joao;20;espanha
carlos;18;portugal
antonio;30;alemanha
```

- How can i get the sum of column 2 (age) -> =87
- How can i get the country that shows more times (portugal)

With this code i get a complete line, but I don't know how get the information above.
I thought convert the data in a matrix (i,j) and access the values, but I don't know how.

CODE:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

std::fstream &GotoLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int num){
    file.seekg(std::ios::beg);
    for(int i=0; i < num - 1; ++i){
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
    return file;
}

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    fstream file("teste.csv");

    GotoLine(file, 2);

    string line2;
    file >> line2;

    cout << line2;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the code as text please, you can write it in question just like you wrote the question itself.

Comment: _"code as image because i cannot post like text"_, of course you can, and are required here to do so!! Check out, how to [format code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: You can split that line further using `std::stringstream` and `std::getline()` with `';'` as delimiting character.

Comment: ok thank you, i didnt found the CTRL-K, but i got it now

Comment: The `console.log()` example from this link is an additional easy method to form code blocks: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `struct` to hold information together in this case, as shown below. You can use the below given program as a reference(starting point) for your future purposes/programs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include<iterator>
struct Person
{
    std::string name, country;
    double age = 0;
    //parameterised constructor
    Person(std::string pname, std::string pcountry,double page): name(pname), country(pcountry), age(page)
    {
        
    }
};


int main()
{
  std::ifstream inputFile("input.txt");
  std::string line,wordAge, tempName, tempCountry;
  double tempAge;
  
  //create a vector of Person objects 
  std::vector<Person> myVec;
  if(inputFile)
  {
      //read the first line and discard it 
      std::getline(inputFile, line);
      //read line by line
      while(std::getline(inputFile, tempName,';'),//read name
            std::getline(inputFile, wordAge,';'),//read age
            std::getline(inputFile, tempCountry,'\n'))//read country
      {
          std::istringstream ss(wordAge);
          if(ss >> tempAge)//read age 
          {
               myVec.emplace_back(tempName, tempCountry,tempAge);
              
          }
         
           
      }
      
  }
  else 
  {
      std::cout<<"Input file cannot be opened"<<std::endl;
  }
    
  //lets print out all the elemnts of the vector to confirm that we read the file correctly
  double sum = 0;
  std::map<std::string, int> myMap;//this will be used to keep track of the count corresponding to each country 
  for(const Person &elem: myVec)
  {
      std::cout <<"Name: "<<elem.name<<" Age: "<<elem.age<<" Country: "<<elem.country<<std::endl;
      sum+=elem.age;
      myMap[elem.country]++;
  }
  std::cout<<"The sum of all ages is: "<<sum <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"The country that occurs most number of times is: "<<(std::prev(myMap.end())->first)<<" which occurred :"<<(std::prev(myMap.end())->second)<<" times"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/95jVpQeO4tcWCumd). The input file can also be found at the above mentioned link.